# Cannot insert duplicate key - creating cases in CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015

I'm getting unhandled exception for specifying that a Duplicate Detection error (none of the duplicate detection rules are enabled in Dynamics CRM for Cases) has occurred.

The message says - 'Cannot insert duplicate key.'

Please help.

Comment: Are you creating them programmatically or through the UI?